# Why is library(Seurat) causing my R session to have a fatal error?

Tags: r, seurat, rstudio

I recently tried to load library(Seurat) after installing Seurat package. It caused my R studio to have a fatal error and abort my session. I have successfully downloaded it before. I have uninstalled R and R studio and reinstalled, restarted my computer. I am new to R too, so I'm not sure what I'm doing.

I am following the directions provided on the satijalab.org website on how to install Seurat.

Here's a screenshot of the error message. [image]

I ran install.packages("Seurat") in R. R is also crashing as soon as I run library(Seurat). Here's a screenshot right before I hit run, and when it crashes, R application just closes.

[image]

Comment: hi @DianaatDuke, looking at the screen shot, seems like it downloaded the package..  i am surprised it doesn't try to install other dependencies, since you installed a new R or Rstudio? can you load other libraries, save library(uwot) , since this is needed for Seurat too

Comment: Yes, no error message when i run the code library(uwot).

Comment: Okay it might be Seurat is not checking for the installation of core dependencies

Comment: I did the same analysis last week and it was actually perfectly fine. So do you think something changed since then?

Comment: i would go crazy if that's the case lol... can you try opening R , preferably use a terminal , powershell whichever you are on, and try to load Seurat.. just check it's not Rstudio

Comment: I am going crazy, it's been 2.5 hours of me trying to figure out what's wrong. R is also crashing. I can run this without problem -  install.packages("Seurat"). As soon as I run library(Seurat), R just crashes.

Comment: it can be solved..ok do you always run R from 1 directory? did you try removing the .Rhistory .Rdata files?https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2012-June/009326.html

Comment: I tried to remove .Rhistory in R studio on the bottom right screen of (under Files tab). but I didn't try removing .Renviron    - where can I find and delete that?

Comment: I'm using my work mac laptop. I actually tried to run this exercise on my personal Mac, and had the same problems. I can borrow a PC laptop and try to do it on there? but ultimately, I need this to run on my mac laptop.

Comment: it's ok, mac makes it easier. So open a terminal (go to applications /utilities or just search). then do ls .R* ; you should see .Rapp.history .Renviron .Rhistory or maybe something more, delete these by doing rm .Rhistory etc..

Comment: I suggest those above because from your R, i can see you are loading .Rapp.history.. whatever that might be. Once all deleted;  type R in the terminal ; and R will be loaded in a terminal. try library(Seurat) then

Comment: this is the message I get when I type in .R* 

GI-C02ZC1G0:~ dl319$ .R*
-bash: .Rapp.history: command not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107003/discussion-between-stupidwolf-and-diana-at-duke).

Comment: @StupidWolf helped me figured it out! Needed to remove r-miniconda and then reinstall Seurat package.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already done so I would make a complete installation of Anaconda, particularly good with bash. The I would either install using Anaconda Navigator, or ...

```
# Create an R environment and activate it
conda create -n r_env r-essentials r-base python=3.7
conda activate r_env

# install Reurat
conda install -c bioconda r-seurat

# installing standard packages
conda install -c r r-randomforest --yes
```

If you have a Mac the instructions are [here](https://www.guru99.com/download-install-r-rstudio.html#4). In some systems you need to just `activate r_env` .

Please note if you've installed e.g. `python3` with **`pip`** a conflict occurs with the Anaconda package.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this question. The solution to your problem is [here](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/2769#issuecomment-1211152502)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).